# Reorder factored matrix columns in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, columnsorting

I have a matrix visual in Power BI. The columns are departments and the rows years. The values are counts of people in each department each year. The departments obviously don't have a natural ordering, BUT I would like to reorder them using the total column count for each department in descending order.

For example, if Department C has 100 people total over the years (rows), and all the other departments have fewer, I want Department C to come first.

I have seen other solutions that add an index column, but this doesn't work very well for me because the "count of people" variable is what I want to index by and that doesn't already exist in my data. Rather it's a calculation based on individual people which each have a department and year.

If anyone can point me to an easy way of changing the column ordering/sorting that would be splendid!

```
      | DeptA | DeptB | DeptC
------|-------|-------|-------
1900  |   2   |   5   |  10
2000  |   6   |   7   |   2
2010  |  10   |   1   |  12
2020  |   0   |   3   |  30
------|-------|-------|-------
Total |  18   |  16   |  54

Order:   #2      #3      #1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do this like there is for sorting the rows (there should be though, so go [vote for a similar idea here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13808061-matrix-sort-columns-by-value)), but here's a possible workaround.

I will assume your source table is called `Employees` and looks something like this:

```
Department  Year   Value
A           1900    2
B           1900    5
C           1900   10
A           2000    6
B           2000    7
C           2000    2
A           2010   10
B           2010    1
C           2010   12
A           2020    0
B           2020    3
C           2020   30
```

First, create a new calculated table like this:

```
Depts = SUMMARIZE(Employees, Employees[Department], "Total", SUM(Employees[Value]))
```

This should give you a short table as follows:

```
Department  Total
A           18
B           16
C           54
```

From this, you can easily rank the totals with a calculated column on this `Depts` table:

```
Rank = RANKX('Depts', 'Depts'[Total])
```

Make sure your new `Depts` table is related to the original `Employees` table on the `Department` column.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Under the Data tab, use Modeling > Sort by Column to sort `Depts[Department]` by `Depts[Rank]`.

[image]

Finally, replace the `Employees[Department]` with `Depts[Department]` on your matrix visual and you should get the following:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I'm not sure if I want to go to the trouble but I appreciate having a solution if I decide I need it